# Getting a route for using in iPhone maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, maps

Before IOS6 We could use Google routes in google maps but on apple maps its not allowed by google to use the route points found by google. Is there any way in new iPhone maps to get all route points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use  `CloudMade` . It has `route-me service`

Comment: Is there any other service except cloudemade because their api for iOS is deprecated.